# How do I edit the rc.local file on my Raspberry using another PC?

Tags: linux, python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, flutter

I edited my rc.local file to start 2 python scripts and a flutter app on boot and I set it up to boot in console mode. But now I can't close the flutter app. I already tried pressing CTRL + Z or CTRL + C, basically all the possible key combinations and nothing happens.

Does somebody have a solution for this?

P.S. The flutter app is running using flutter-pi and the python scripts don't have any UI or something like that. They are used to execute functions when a button in the app is pressed.

Comment: As in remote access [SSH, serial] or copying the file to another PC for editing and copying it back [SSH, serial]?

Comment: And if neither ssh nor serial works, take out SD card, put in SD reader on different computer, and edit. While you are doing that, enable ssh as well, for the future.

Comment: I'll try editing it from another PC using the SD card method. For some reason I forgot that you can do that haha.

Comment: So the SC card method didn't work. It says I need to format the SD card for the PC to be able to read it. So @JW0914 could you please explain how to do the both ways you recommended?

Comment: I don't think there's anything that allows WRITE access to ext4 under Win10/11 yet (assuming that's what you're running), but you could boot into a linux live CD (/USB drive) of your choosing and do it that way.

Comment: I solved the problem, I booted it in safe mode by plugging the SD card into another PC and editing the cmdline.txt by adding " init=/bin/bash" on the end of the line. Thanks either way!

Comment: @MiG Paragon's [LinuxFs for Windows](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/linuxfs-windows/) allows reading/writing to ext2/3/4, as well as checking/repairing filesystem corruption for ext2/3/4.

Comment: @TinPocrnic I've never used a Pi before, but it should have a USB-to-TTL serial header for a FTDI [USB-TTL cable](https://ftdichip.com/product-category/products/cables/usb-ttl-serial-cable-series/) _(ensure correct voltage is used, either 3.3v or 5v, with FTDI chips being the most reliable/highest quality)_ or an FTDI [USB-to-TTL board](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00NAY1VJ2) _(comes in a variety of forms)_. You would use the FTDI USB-to-TTL cable/board to access the Pi via a serial session in PuTTY. SSH is straightforward to set up and guides can be found via a search engine.